# Google Maps API Infowindow Inputing lat and lng Values into Form Hidden Field before Submit

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am trying to input **'lat'** and **'lng'** values into a form hidden field embedded within an infowindow. Upon submitting the form, the form will call a function that appends the **'lat'** and **'lng'** values into the hidden fields before posting it.

However, I face issues when trying to pass the values of **'lat'** and **'lng'** into the hidden fields.

```
//declare global variables
var map = null; 
var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// handles the initial settings and styling for google maps 
function initialize() {
      var map_options = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.35208, 103.81984),
        panControl: false,
        panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        },

        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: false
      }

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), map_options); 
     //add marker to the event where the point of the map is clicked
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { add_marker(event.latLng); });
} 


function add_marker(location) {
    map.markers = []; 
    //ensure that the map is initialized
    if(map != null) { 
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: location, 
        map: map, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP });

        //listener on markers to listen for clicks/right clicks 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) { marker.setMap(null); });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { open_info(marker, location) });
        map.markers.push(marker); 
    }
}

function open_info(marker, location) {
    if(map != null) {
        //infowindow form that calls appendLatLng() before submit
        var content =   '<form method="post" action="main.php" onsubmit="return appendLatLng(location)" name="infoWindow" id="infoWindow">' +
                        '<input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder= "Location"/><br />' +
                        '<input type="textarea" name="description" id="description" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Description"/><hr />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value=""/>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" value=""/>' +
                        '<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" />' +
                        '</form>';


        info_window.setContent(content);
        info_window.open(map, marker);
    }
}

//append location.lat() and location.lng() to lat and lng fields
function appendLatLng(location){
    document.getElementById('lat').value = location.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = location.lng();
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The following is the php code segment in *main.php* that attempts to access the lat and lng values, but I am getting null values.

```
    <?php
        if (!empty($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['description'])){
    ?>
        <h5><b>Name of Location:</b> <?=$_POST['location']?>
        <b>Description:</b> <?=$_POST['description']?> 
        <b>Longtitude:</b> <?=$_POST['lng']?>
        <b>Latitude:</b> <?=$_POST['lat']?></h5>    
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I am wondering if its a problem of me passing the "location" object as I call the appendLatLng() function. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Try to put `appendLatLng(location);` after `info_window.open(map, marker);` and check with Inspect Element if you use chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the onsubmit-handler doesn't know the `location`-variable, it will not be executed in the scope of `open_info()`  (in the onsubmit-handler `location` will be a DOMNode, the input with the ID "location")

Set the desired values directly  when you prepare the form:

```
var content =   '<form method="post" action="main.php" name="infoWindow" id="infoWindow">' +
                '<input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder= "Location"/><br />' +
                '<input type="textarea" name="description" id="description" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Description"/><hr />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="'+marker.getPosition().lat()+'"/>' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" value="'+marker.getPosition().lng()+'"/>' +
                '<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" />' +
                '</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your `appendLatLng(location);` after `info_window.open(map, marker);`. For testing purpose, make input id lat and lng to text and you can see the value is added when you clicked the marker.